# Creating couple actors on same stage

Tags: java, libgdx

I learn now to use actors on stage. It uses for this purpose guide:
[LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPIeERAm2ao)

Created MyActor class and it uses texture.
For each new actor I have to do a new class? I see that when drawing the scene does not specify Which one draw the texture is only draws the class MyActor.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on what you're asking? what exactly are you trying and what is happening. Maybe provide a small snippet of code.

Comment: I create an actor in a new class. Then it adds an object from a class with the actor to the stage, then I draw stage. Stage draws me everything in this class where the actor is.
My question - I should create a brand new class for each actors or I should put every new actors to the same class?

Answer (score 1):

If a Texture is the only additional functionality you need over the plain Actor class, you can look into the LibGDX "Image" class. This is essentially an Actor which has a Drawable associated with it. So you can extend Image instead of Actor if you need it to have a drawing component.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html